# How do I know my selector is correct in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of HTML code:

```
<div class="myclass" id ="class1">
  <ol class="list">
     <li id="li_1">
         <input id="input_1" …>
         <acronym id="input_1" class="classabc">
      </li>
      <li id="li_2">
          <input id="input_2" …>
          <acronym id="input_2" class="classabc">
      </li>
        ....
      <li id="li_n">
          <input id="input_n" …>
          <acronym id="input_n" class="classabc">
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the class of some acronym tags, I have the id of an acronym tag, so I tried this:

```
$('acronym#'+id).removeClass('classabc');
$('acronym#'+id).addClass('newclass');
```

It didn't work so I tried:

```
$('div.myclass ol acronym#'+id).removeClass('classabc');
$('div.myclass ol acronym#'+id).addClass('newclass');
```

But it still doesn't work.
I tried alert inside the code, the alert works. I am thinking my selector is not right. So I am asking is there anyway to get correct selector? Or how do I know my selector is correct?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `'acronym#_' + id`?

Comment: What is the value of `id`, and is the code running when the DOM is ready?

Comment: FYI, IDs are unique, so there's no need to include the tag name before it. That only adds an additional (unnecessary) check.

Comment: [jsFiddle][1] is your friend. use it to test stuff like this. [1]:http://www.jsfiddle.net/

Comment: are you sure that the value of "id" is for example "input_2"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem here: The id attribute MUST be unique for the document. You used the same id attribute several times and this will lead to no (or unpredictable) results using an id selector!

Comment: Confirmed, at least in IE. Remember, jQuery is a helper, not a means of DOM rule enforcement.

Answer (score 5):

It is not proper to have the same `id` declared for two elements.

Remove the `id` from `acronym` and then use the following javascript.

```
<input id="input_1">
<acronym class="classabc">
```

Where `var id = "input_1";`

```
$('#'+ id).siblings('acronym').removeClass('classabc');
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnYYK/12/)

Here is a w3schools link to learning css selectors. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: But the `acronym` part while superfluous, isn't invalid, so its removal won't change the outcome of the code.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that the OP had duplicate IDs. Hard to say what `'#' + id` will do. Probably will grab the first one it finds, but you can never be sure with invalid markup.

Comment: I am making the assumption that the `id` he is passing in `'#'+ id` is a local variable of the id he wants to select.

Comment: I just meant that since `$('#'+ id)` uses `document.getElementById`, we can assume it will grab the first duplicate it finds, but it wouldn't be necessarily guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

The basic selector you'd be looking for should look something like this (since you have duplicate ids):

```
$('acronym[id='input_n'])
```

so you'd need to include the closing quotes:

```
$("acronym[id='input_" + n + "']")
```

**Note:** Since there are duplicate ids, this answer isn't using the more common `$('#input_n')` selector.

Comment: That's not right. Your selector would be looking for `<acronym id="'input_2'"...>`

Comment: @RightSaidFred, you are correct - I typed too fast and submitted before I had finished editing.

Comment: Answer has been edited from its original, but why use an `id` filter instead of the `#` id selector?

Comment: Ah, I see, duplicate IDs are used in the question. +1 Though a note on using dupes is probably in order. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the id's on the page should be unique for every dom element. Considering that if you want to find any element by Id you can just use id selector. Try this

```
$('#'+id).removeClass('classabc');
$('#'+id).addClass('newclass');
```